# How to only show specific columns in ui-grid.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I have json data (REST response) with many (partly nested) parameters but only want to show specif ones.

How to hide all and enable only specific ones? Currently all parameters are shown as columns.

So I do not want to hide one-by-one by excludeParameters or columnDef visible = false (because the list of parameters can be different based on REST response).

Do you have any idea?
My intension is to change the default visibility to false and only the wanted parameters to true (via columnDef visible). Any solution for that?

Thanks in advance,
  Chris

Comment: Is the list of columns that you want to show going to be known before-hand? If so, can you just have a set of column defs that specifies what to show and then leave all the others out?

Comment: When I specify two or three columns the rest is also visible

Comment: Are you sure you're setting up your columnDefs correctly? In this example the data set has 15 columns but only 7 are set up to be shown: http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/103_filtering

Comment: Thank you for the example. I found the issue. GridOptions were not used caused by a failure in HTML tag when including the ui.grid. Now columns are shown as expected.

Answer (score 0):

My table options looks like this

```
    $scope.tableOptions= {

            data : [],
            columnDefs :[
                { field : 'firstName'},
                { field : 'middelName'},
                { field : 'lastName' }
            ]
     }
```

and I am using the directive as

```
<div ui-grid="tableOptions"></div>
```

the data will be populated inside the data field of $scope.tableOptions once the rest api fetches result

Each Json object in my case is having more than 10 fields but the table is only showing three fields which I have defined in columnDefs